# Gulp in Ionic is not compiling sass file

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, gulp

Yesterday I started a new project and added ionic setup sass and it all worked fine.

Now continue working today on it and gulp is not working, with no changes done from yesterday, and I got this error message below.

```
Error: Missing error message
    at new PluginError (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\gulp-util\lib\PluginError.js:53:28)
    at DestroyableTransform.logError (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:178:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at onwriteError (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:322:10)
    at onwrite (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:339:11)
    at WritableState.onwrite (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:123:5)
    at afterTransform (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:81:3)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:58:12)
    at errorM (D:\Dev\pprs\pprs\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:133:14)
```

Comment: Weird error. Try to delete node_modules and run `npm install` again? !(back up node_modules first and make sure you installed your dependencies with `npm install --save`!

Comment: I just did ionic setup sass again on same folder and it works now... not sure what caused the issue in the first place.

Comment: Hmmm. Last time I checked, on windows, the SASS implementation is the dodgiest thing ever. I think that's because the C++ port of sass `libsass` isn't ready for primetime yet. Stuff like this happens to me all the time on windows

Comment: Same error here. I'm using Windows 10. Quite weird

Comment: @goran you should add like answer how you solve it: "did ionic setup sass again". It works for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Solution was to do a sass setup again. So I just `ionic setup sass` and it was OK from then on.

Still not sure why this happened in the first place...